# If I uninstall Windows will Ubuntu be uninstalled?

Tags: installation, windows, uninstall

I have a problem with my Windows XP SP3, it shows blue screen in normal mode and in safe mode (both). So, I decided to uninstall Windows XP SP3 and re-install again. But I am confused. Will it uninstall Ubuntu or not?

Comment: Well, how is Ubuntu installed? Is this a dual boot machine or a Wubi install?

Comment: yes, it is on dual boot, when i start my PC, it shows options, which: Windows XP Professional or Ubuntu. But I know that I installed it with Wubi program in Windows.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu with Wubi, yes, if not, absolutely no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to let you know, a Wubi install is not considered a "dual boot", but I got what you meant. Wubi is actually installed inside Windows.

You should be able to use this thing called "[Wubi move](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi)" which will port your Wubi install inside windows OUTSIDE OF WINDOWS allowing you to delete windows and leave Ubuntu in one piece.

Comment: so, if I uninstall Windows without Wubi move, it will uninstall Ubuntu too, yes?

Comment: oh, and my ubuntu is installed to disk C:, but my Windows is installed to disk E:. So, in this condition I must use Wubi move again?

Comment: Yes. I will play a little example. You may be familiar with Windows machines that have Windows XP and 7 on them and have a similar screen, this screen is Windows based and is not a GRUB loader. Like that, Wubi installs Ubuntu alongside Windows as if it where another Windows OS, so without moving your installation outside Windows, upon deletion of Windows, Ubuntu would also be deleted.

Comment: so, in my condition (C: and E:) Ubuntu will be deleted too, yes?

Comment: No.. Wubi move operates from Ubuntu so it doesn't care about Windows drive letters. Just make sure you get your sda's and sda's right though.

Comment: If you uninstall Windows yes. Note something, once you run that script your computer will boot INTO your new standalone version of Ubuntu.. You will need to go into GParted and manually delete the old Windows partitions, as far as I am aware of.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't understand you, I say that, my Ubuntu and Windows, each of them are in another disks, one of them in `simple` local disk C:, and Windows is on `system` local disk E:, Ubuntu will not be removed?

Comment: Quick question, separate hard drives or separate Logical drives (Hard Drive Partitions)?

Comment: What @SeanWebber is trying to say is that if you installed Ubuntu using Wubi you installed Ubuntu inside your Windows Operating System. As a result, if you uninstall Windows Ubuntu will also be uninstalled. But if you created another partition in your hard drive where you installed Ubuntu, they will not be removed if you uninstall Windows. If they are in separate hard drives no problem either.

Comment: @SeanWebber separate logical drives.

Comment: @Nick knows what I'm getting at :) You need to run Wubi, then once your sure it worked, delete Windows (deleting your old Wubi Ubuntu installation in the process.)

Comment: Thanks very much! :) You helped me a lot! @Nick thank you too! I understood, I installed Ubuntu in Windows, but to another logical drive, so, my Ubuntu will not be installed. :)

Comment: And one another question, what about boot? If I re-install Windows XP again, it will dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu again?

Comment: I may be wrong, but as far as I know, Windows Install discs tend to just WIPE EVERYTHING upon installation, this is why Dual Boot tutorials say to install Windows first THEN Ubuntu, Windows Live CDs have no "Install Grubloader" option..

Comment: ok, thansk! i will try ;)